# Insert SQL with parameters causes "Incorect syntax near the keyword 'values'"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I want to populate a table in mssql with the values entered by the user (the error comes from the NumericUpDown) and I'm using this code:

```
 string cs= "Data Source=CODRINMA\\CODRINMA;Initial Catalog=BusManager; Trusted_Connection=True;";
 string insert = "INSERT INTO TipAutocar ([IDTipAutocar], [Marca], [Model], [Nrlocuri] values ([@TipAutocar], [@Marca], [@Model], [@Nrlocuri]))";
try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDTipAutocar", txtID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Marca", txtMarca.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", txtModel.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nrlocuri", nmrLocuri.Value);
        int valoare = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(valoare + "Tipul de autocar a fost adaugat cu succes!", "BusManager");

    }
}
catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show(er.Message); }
```

But, when I press button to insert, I'm having the following error and I can't figure it out what's to do:

> Incorect syntax near the keyword 'values'.

Comment: What is `insert` exactly? You didn't mentioned the most important part of your problem.

Comment: Show the sql query. The error comes from the database. It seems that you are using the keyword `values` incorrectly.

Comment: Missing a `)` before `values`... voting to close as simple typographical error, this does not have any redeeming value for anyone else.

Comment: > Must declare the scalar variable "@TipAutocar" .. I am getting this error

Comment: @TimSchmelter That statement is a non-sequitur.  There is nothing to be learned from correcting a typo.  It's a close reason for a reason.

Comment: @CodrinAfrasinei  This is now a separate question.  If you have a new question, ask it as a new question.  If you want a hint, take it from the answer to this question - read what you have typed and make sure there are no errors.  Check the parameters in your query - then check the parameters you have given values to.  Do you notice any problems?

Comment: @J... thanks for the tip. I will be more carefully next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm missing a closing round parenthesis before `values` here:

```
string insert = "INSERT INTO TipAutocar ([IDTipAutocar], [Marca], [Model], [Nrlocuri] values ([@IDTipAutocar], [@Marca], [@Model], [@Nrlocuri]))";
```

You are not allowed to  use `[]` around the parameters, otherwise it's not a parameter and you'll get an error f.e. "invalid columnname [@TipAutocar]".

You also name the  parameter `@TipAutocar` but you add it as `IDTipAutocar`.
Also, always use the correct type, all the more if you use `AddWithValue` which infers the type from the value. So i guess that `IDTipAutocar` is an `int`, then parse it to one before:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDTipAutocar", int.Parse(txtID.Text));
```

As an aside, i'm always using a verbatim string literal. On that way i can format my sql query as i want, even with multiple lines. This should work as exptected:

```
string insert = @"INSERT INTO TipAutocar
                     ( IDTipAutocar, Marca, Model, Nrlocuri )
                  VALUES 
                     ( @IDTipAutocar, @Marca, @Model, @Nrlocuri)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this bracket;

```
string insert = "INSERT INTO TipAutocar ([IDTipAutocar], [Marca], [Model], [Nrlocuri] values (@TipAutocar, [@Marca, @Model, @Nrlocuri))";
                                       ^^^
```

You close it at the end of your query, you should close it just before your `VALUES` part.

Change it to;

```
string insert = "INSERT INTO TipAutocar ([IDTipAutocar], [Marca], [Model], [Nrlocuri]) values (@TipAutocar, @Marca, @Model, @Nrlocuri)";
                                        ^^^                                         ^^^
```

You <strike>don't need</strike> are not allowed to use square brackets for your parameters by the way. Also use `using` statement to dispose your `SqlCommand` as well. And since you used this statement for your `SqlConnection`, you don't need to close it with `con.Close()` because this statement do that automaticaly.

Also you define your parameter name as `@TipAutocar` in your command but try to add parameter name as `@IDTipAutocar` which does not match. Change your parameter name like;

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipAutocar", txtID.Text);
```

And don't use `AddWithValue` anymore. [It *may* generate unexpected results](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `.Add()` method overloads instead to specify your [`SqlDbType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) and parameter size.

Comment: _"You don't need to use"_ you are not allowed to use them ;)

Comment: I'm getting this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@TipAutocar"

Comment: @CodrinAfrasinei Because you define your parameter name as `@TipAutocar` in your command bu you try to add parameter named with `@IDTipAutocar` which they are not match. These named parameters have to be same. Updated my answer, take a look.